# Django Comments Xtd Comments are not nesting

Tags: django, django-comments

I followed the tutorial on https://django-comments-xtd.readthedocs.io, everything seems to work find, the forms and the comments are working, but on the website they are not displayed properly.

instead of looking like this:

[image]

They all look like this

[image]

The reply  is not nesting under the comment

but in the admin its working you can see how it nests

take a look:

[image]

Please help

Comment: Does anyone have a clue???

Comment: Please help me. Do you need additional information?

Answer (score 0):

Try add css class container in the comment_tree.html

```html
<div class="container media">
```